# why the answers and comments has been removed from this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I read a question and commented on it and there was an answer also on this question why it has been removed and who removed it..

the question is here.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/i-am-drawing-a-picture-of-mohammed-what-did-he-look-like

Comment: I commented on this question but it was removed today I was think same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was only one answer to that question, which was heavily flagged and deleted (as much for plagiarism as for being offensive), but that wasn't until *after* you posted this meta question.  There was no other answer posted or deleted.

As for the deleted comments, they were flagged as being non-constructive.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea if one of the mods contact [the user 8306](http://islam.stackexchange.com/users/8306/). The user seems to be here not for learning but for preaching his anti-Islam views.